# Python MYSQL update

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-python

I am using this below code to update the records of my table but it doesn't work and it doesn't update my table

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                   database='rps',
                                   user='root',
                                   password='')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""UPDATE players SET score=%s WHERE chat_id =%s""", (int(self.p1.score), str(self.p1.chat__id)))
    cur.execute("""UPDATE players SET score=%s WHERE chat_id =%s""", (int(self.p2.score), str(self.p2.chat__id)))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

It is completely true but i don't know how to solve this problem 
Can you help me to solve it guys ?
Thanks

Comment: no one doesn't know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set try/catch on your query execution:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(some_statement)
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, e: 
    # handle a specific error condition
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    # handle a generic error condition
except MySQLdb.Warning, e:
    # handle warnings, if the cursor you're using raises them
```

If you don't catch any exceptions, you should check your program logic.